# Unable to only update a datacard if the related field is visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have 2 fields, one of type number and the other of type DateTime. and i want to only submit their values incase they are set to visible.

I tired this formula on the Update property, but even if the fields are hidden the values will be submitted/updated, any advice?

[image]

Comment: Are you using patch function or submitform function to save data?

Comment: @GaneshSanap submit form. thanks

Comment: @GaneshSanap any idea why this is not working?